# Input is a String array, Output is an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, type-conversion

My problem consists, that I want to insert a `String[]` into an `ArrayList`, this works fine.

Whilst trying to get my `String[]` from the `ArrayList`, I only receive an `ArrayList` in return. Is there any way I can retrieve my `String[]`.

I cannot seem to find the method that could solve this problem. I would like to restrain myself from programming around it.

```java
public ArrayList<String> getAllAttributes() throws IOException {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vmxConfigFile));
  ArrayList<String> attributes = new ArrayList<String>();

  for(int i = 0 ; i < getAmountOfAttributes() ; i++) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String[] attribute = line.split("="); 
    attributes.addAll(Arrays.asList(attribute));
  }

  return attributes;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  VMXConverter vmx = new VMXConverter("file:///C://Users//trisi//Downloads//vCloud-Availability.vmx_ ");
  ArrayList<String> list = vmx.getAllAttributes();

  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    // What i want to do: String[] x = list.get(i);
    String x = list.get(i); <--this is currently my only option
  }
}
```

I expect, that when I grab the element in my list, it should be an array of size 2, with 2 keywords.

Instead, I get a list in which the Elements are no longer sorted as arrays

Comment: Start from making type of your list a `String[]` instead of just `String`. You'll get compile errors, resolve those. Boom, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not adding the Array of Strings to your arraylist, instead you add all elements of the String array to the arraylist, so You'll only get one big arraylist.

What you can do is not return with an arraylist of string, but an arraylist of string array:

```java
public ArrayList<String[]> getAllAttributes() throws IOException {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vmxConfigFile));
  ArrayList<String[]> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

  for(int i = 0 ; i < getAmountOfAttributes() ; i++) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    String[] attribute = line.split("="); 
    attributes.add(attribute);
  }

  return attributes;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  VMXConverter vmx = new VMXConverter("file:///C://Users//trisi//Downloads//vCloud-Availability.vmx_ ");
  ArrayList<String[]> list = vmx.getAllAttributes();

  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String[] x = list.get(i); 
  }
}
```

However I do not think you want this. If I understand well you have a file containing key=value pairs. I suggest load them into a Map, so it will be much more easier to work with.

You can load to map like this:

```java
public Map<String,String> getAllAttributesMap() throws IOException {
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vmxConfigFile));
  Map<String,String> attributes = new HashMap<>();

  while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
     String[] attribute = line.split("="); 
     if(attribute.length>0 && attribute[0]!=null) 
        attributes.put(attribute[0],attribute.length<1?null:attribute[1]); //just to avoid null pointer problems...
  } 

  return attributes;
}
```

And so you can easily get a value of a key from the map.

```java
Map<String,String> attributes=getAllAttributesMap();
System.out.println("Value of foo: "+attributes.get("foo"));
System.out.println("Value of bar: "+attributes.get("bar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ArrayList < String[] > instead ArrayList < String >.

Something like this:

```
public ArrayList<String[]> getAllAttributes() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vmxConfigFile));
    ArrayList<String[]> attributes = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < getAmountOfAttributes() ; i++) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] attribute = line.split("=");
        attributes.add(attribute);
    }

    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, dont know what i was thinking :D

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have a list of Strings. When you add the String[] to the list each single element of the array will be added separately to the list.
If you want to keep the arrays as they are, then you need to use a list of String[].

```
public ArrayList<String[]> getAllAttributes() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vmxConfigFile));
    ArrayList<String[]> attributes = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < getAmountOfAttributes() ; i++) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] attribute = line.split("="); 
        attributes.add(attribute);
    }

    return attributes;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    VMXConverter vmx = new VMXConverter("file:///C://Users//trisi//Downloads//vCloud-Availability.vmx_ ");
    ArrayList<String[]> list = vmx.getAllAttributes();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       String[] x = list.get(i);
    }
}
```